# Auto Layout Contraints Differ With Hide Tab In viewDidLoad

Tags: view, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, constraints, autolayout

I built my project as a `Tab Bar` Application that utilizes the `UITabBarController`.

I've set all the auto layout constraints for all my subviews and it looks right in the preview. When my application first starts, I hide the tab bar in `viewDidLoad`. Once a button is clicked, I hide the view and show the `tab bar`.

My problem is that the constraints adjusted themselves to the hidden tool bar and everything shifts down the length of the height of the tab bar. If I go to the second tab and back to the first, the constraints are back to normal. Is there an easy way to deal with this? I need to find out how to either hide the tab bar in other way that doesn't compromise my constraints, or how to allow the first view to extend down over the tab bar. Please help.

Hiding tab bar liks so.

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

Oddly enough. When I go to set the vertical constraint to the bottom of the view, the distance to the bottom of the view is equal to the top of the tab bar even though the height of the tab bar is 50 px.

Comment: You need to compensate for the extra space that you are getting after hiding the `UITabbar`.

Comment: Is it possible to have a look at the code?

Comment: I tried compensating the extra space but that doesn't work because once you go to the second tab and back to the first, the constraints are all skewed up.